# Install succeeds, but I can't find the storefront

Tags: installation

So after following all of the prerequisite instructions and having to upgrade my Ubuntu 20.04 VPS to appease ElasticSearch, the install of Magento CE v2.4.3 succeeds:

```
[user]:[path]$ sudo /var/www/html/storefront/magento-project/bin/magento setup:install \
> --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
> --admin-firstname=[redacted] --admin-lastname=[redacted] --admin-email=[redacted] \
> --admin-user=[redacted] --admin-password=[redacted] \
> --language=en_US \
> --currency=USD \
> --timezone=America/New_York \
> --base-url=https://localhost/store/ \
> --base-url-secure=https://localhost/store/ --use-secure=1 --use-secure-admin=1 \
> --use-rewrites=1 \
> --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200

[...]

[Progress: 1386 / 1386]
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin_[redacted]
Nothing to import.
[user]:[path]$ _
```

But it's like nothing happened. Both going to [myRedactedDomain].com/store remotely and `curl`ing localhost/store locally result in 404. What exactly did the installation do? Isn't there supposed to be a dummy page there?

I have already searched for an answer on here but part of the problem is that there's no obvious way to phrase my question because it is ambiguous.

Do all my install option parameters look okay? I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Magento2.4.2 onwards, magento2 loads from pub directory of the magneto2 directory.

Comment: That was the problem! I didn't know I had to change the DocumentRoot. Thank you.